# How to stream video with netcat

Tags: pipe, raspberry-pi, streaming, nc

I'd like to have Raspberry Pi stream video, so I'm doing this:

```
raspivid ... -o - | nc -l -k 4242
```

But the problem is that the pipe or `nc`, is caching the data until someone connects. But I don't want to do that. I want to drop all data, until someone connects.

Comment: So why not stream video with a real-time protocol that's meant for streaming video?

Answer (score 1):

You've set up a listening TCP socket, which requires a client to connect before data can flow. But even if you set up a UDP socket instead you'd likely end up having the client connect midstream without any of the metadata that defines how the stream should be interpreted.

If you have a protocol that provides metadata on a frequent and regular basis you could try a UDP socket. My version of `nc` doesn't have the `-k` option but I'm aware there are (at least) two different versions available, so I can't give you a tested command-line example.

---

If you want to stream video you should use a purpose built piece of software. It's a complex technology area (a complex legal area, too, as there are many patents) and unless you're streaming something simple such as MJPEG you're unlikely to have any success whatsoever with a naïve solution such as `netcat`.

Some examples of software applications can be found from the likes of [Videolan](https://www.videolan.org/), [Icecast](http://icecast.org/), [Opencast](http://www.opencast.org/software), or [Red5](http://red5.org/).

---

Actually, reading some [documentation for `raspivid`](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/camera/raspicam/raspivid.md) it seems that you could use a listener such as that offered by `xinetd` or `systemd` to handle the incoming connection, and then start `raspivid` once the TCP connection is established. You still don't get any flow control or real-time bandwidth management, but in a controlled network you might achieve your aim satisfactorily.

Comment: Not entirely true. H.264 has Annex B format, which puts metadata (SPS, PPS) before each keyframe. It's purpose is exactly that, to be able to decode video mid-stream.

Comment: @Pitel ah ok, I didn't know about Annex B. I've used MPEG and H.264, and for H.264 I ended up needing to use a streamer (although I can't remember which one we finally settled on - it was well over five years ago). Question amended.